# what is wrong with this code a guess game in python

Tags: python

```
import random
print ("welcome to my game")

guessestaken = 0
number = random.randint(1,10)

print ("what is your name")

myname = raw_input()

print ("Well,"+ myname + "," + "I'm thinking of a number between  1 and 10"

while guessesTaken < 6:
    print ("take a guess")
    guess = raw_input()
    guess = int(guess)
    guesstaken = guesstaken + 1

    if guess < number :
        print  ("your guess is low")
    if guess > number :
        print  ("your guess is high")
    if guess == number :
        break
if guess == number :
    print ("You are awesome ")
    guesstaken = str(guessestaken)
    print ("You guessed the number in " + guessestaken + " try" )

if guess != number:
    print "You lost"
```

Everytime I try to execute it the error "  while guessesTaken < 6:
            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax" appear

Comment: You're missing a closing paren after "1 and 10"

Comment: you miss spelled gusestaken (capitals)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

falsetru already answered your question. You also switch freely between `guessesTaken`, `guesstaken` and `guessestaken`. I just want to add, that python has a nice control statement for determining if a loop has been finished because of being expleted or broken (by `break`). In these cases you can use `while...else`.

In your code it would look like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import random

number = random.randint(1, 10)
print ('Welcome to my game.')

myName = input ('What is your name? ')
print ('Well, {}, I\'m thinking of a number between 1 and 10'.format (myName) )

guessesTaken = 0
while guessesTaken < 6:
    guess = int (input ('Take a guess: ') )
    guessesTaken += 1

    if guess < number: print  ('Your guess is low.')
    if guess > number: print  ('Your guess is high.')
    if guess == number:
        print ('You guessed the number in {} tr{}.'.format (guessesTaken, 'y' if guessesTaken == 1 else 'ies') )
        break
else: print ('You lost.')
```

Answer (score 2):

`print` statement before the `while` statement omit closing parenthesis:

```
print ("Well,"+ myname + "," + "I'm thinking of a number between  1 and 10"
```

Remove opening parenthesis or append closing parenthesis.